# Is there any MySQL 5.8 version?

Tags: mysql

I got a practical test from a company that I had applied for intern. It says use MySQL 5.8 version but I checked internet there is no MySQL 5.8 version. There is MySQL 5.7 and 8. I am confused right now

Is MySQL version 5.8 means, MySQL 5.7.8 or MySQL 8.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no MySQL 5.8. The 5.7 release was in 2015 and it's support ends in 2023. Support for 5.6 ended earlier this year so you can safely rule it out.

It's possible that the person who sent you the task isn't aware that the options are to use 5.7.x or 8.0.

Figuring this out for yourself and asking them to clarify which they meant could also be part of their process!